# how to disable all remaining numbers once 5 random number as been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the javascript I am using to pick the numbers by adding class active to any selected numbers, I use the javascript math to pick 5 numbers and add active class to any clicked number, but I want to disable all remaining numbers once 5 numbers has been selected.
thanks for any help to be renderd

[41.207.248.188:8088/home](http://41.207.248.188:8088/home)

```
  [1]: http://41.207.248.188:8088/home


<div class="play-card">
                  <button type="button" class="close-play-card"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                  <div class="play-card-inner text-center">
                    <div class="play-card-header">
                      <span class="number-amount">Pick 5 Numbers</span>
                      <div class="header-btn-area">
                        <button type="button" id="random2" class="myBtn2">quick pick</button>
                        <input type="text" id="firstleg2" size="5" value="5" style="display:none"/>
                        <input type="text" id="secondleg2" size="1" value="1" style="display:none"/>
                        <button type="button" id="remove2">clear</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="play-card-body play-card-body2">
                      <ul class="number-list">
                        <li class="select3" value="1">1</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="2">2</li >
                        <li class="select3" value="3">3</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="4">4</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="5">5</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="6">6</li >
                        <li class="select3" value="7">7</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="8">8</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="9">9</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="10">10</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="11">11</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="12">12</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="13">13</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="14">14</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="15">15</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="16">16</li >
                        <li class="select3" value="17">17</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="18">18</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="19">19</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="20">20</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="21">21</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="22">22</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="23">23</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="24">24</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="25">25</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="26">26</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="27">27</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="28">28</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="29">29</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="30">30</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="31">31</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="32">32</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="33">33</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="34">34</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="35">35</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="36">36</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="37">37</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="38">38</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="39">39</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="40">40</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="41">41</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="42">42</li >
                        <li class="select3" value="43">43</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="44">44</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="45">45</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="46">46</li >
                        <li class="select3" value="47">47</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="48">48</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="49">49</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="50">50</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="51">51</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="52">52</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="53">53</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="54">54</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="55">55</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="56">56</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="57">57</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="58">58</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="59">59</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="60">60</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="61">61</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="62">62</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="63">63</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="64">64</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="65">65</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="66">66</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="67">67</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="68">68</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="69">69</li>
                        <li class="select3" value="70">70</li>                                                       
                      </ul>
                      <span class="add-more-text">Select Special ball</span>
                      <ul class="number-list">
                        <li class="select4" value="1">1</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="2">2</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="3">3</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="4">4</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="5">5</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="6">6</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="7">7</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="8">8</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="9">9</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="10">10</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="11">11</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="12">12</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="13">13</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="14">14</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="15">15</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="16">16</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="17">17</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="18">18</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="19">19</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="20">20</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="21">21</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="22">22</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="23">23</li>
                        <li class="select4" value="24">24</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="25">25</li>
                        <li  class="select4" value="26">26</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="play-card-footer">
                      <p class="play-card-footer-text">Selected Numbers:</p>
                      <div class="selected-numbers">
                     <p class="green" id="print2"> <input class="green"  type="textbox" style="text-align: center;"   name="play1" formControlName="play1" id="print2"  value="" ></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
    <script>
    function shuffle(array) {
        var m = array.length, t, i;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle…
        while (m) {

          // Pick a remaining element…
          i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

          // And swap it with the current element.
          t = array[m];
          array[m] = array[i];
          array[i] = t;
        }

        return array;

      }


      $(function() {
          $("#random2").click(function() {
              var $all = $(".select3").removeClass("active");
           //  if counter <= 5
              $(shuffle($all).slice(0, $("#firstleg2").val())).addClass("active");
              var $all = $(".select4").removeClass("active");
              $(shuffle($all).slice(0, $("#secondleg2").val())).addClass("active");
          });
      });
        </script>
    <script>
      function shuffle(array) {
      var m = array.length, t, i;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle…
      while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
      }

      return array;
    }
      $(function() {
        $("#remove2").click(function() {
            var $all = $(".select3").removeClass("active");
            var $all = $(".select4").removeClass("active");
            document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = "";
        });

      });
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#myBtn2").click(function(){
              var idArr = [];
              $(".active").each(function(){
                  idArr.push($(this).attr("value"));
              });

              // Join array elements and display in alert
              idArr.join(", ");
          document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = idArr;
          });
      });
      </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".play-card-body2").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        var idArr = [];
            $(".active").each(function(){
                idArr.push($(this).attr("value"));
            });

            // Join array elements and display in alert
            idArr.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = idArr;
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can add global counter (maybe input type hidden) and increase it on every choice and then check if counter is = 5, then block all numbers that don't have class active

Comment: can you show me a sample script for that?

Comment: Please don't ask people to create any accounts. The question should contain the necessary info without that kind of steps. You're really limiting the number of people that's going to help you.

Comment: ok, Thanks @james Z, i am new to stack overflow, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Script to disable numbers when counter would be something like this

```js
function disableNumbers() {
    var counter = $(".counter");
    if (counter.val() == 5) {
        alert("FIVE NUMBERS ARE SELECTED");
        $(".number-list").find("li").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("disabled");
        })
    } else {
        counter.attr("value", parseInt(counter.val()) + 1);
        alert(counter.val());

    }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="0" class="counter">
<button onclick="disableNumbers()">Reserve</button>
```

But of course, for this snippet to work, you must include jQuery

Comment: this is only counting 5 click, what i want is to only allow 5 numbers to be selected , any time the class called active is up to 5 on the .number-list li it should disable the rest li, and if one click anyone from the 5 selected it should be able to update to the number by reducing one, do you understand me @Armin ?

Comment: Well modify code so it works for you. I gave you 80% of solution

Comment: thanks but , this is only 40% solution, i am trying to call the function to disable my li once i make 5 selection, but the code is only working for and 5 click even if its not selecting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a java script counter, first check if the class 'active' on the numbers is =5 den disable or set the remaining numbers with class "select" as d case may be from your code . remember do not use a click event counter since a quick pick can also give you 5 selected numbers with only one click.